# Find rows in pandas dataframes, with at least 3 columns exactly the same as another row

Tags: python, pandas

Given a df like so, with index id:

```
Id  | age    | gender| occupation  | region | height | weight(kg)
100 | 16     | 0     | "plumber"   | na     | 169    | 20
300 | 50     | 1     | na          | africa | 12     | 90
600 | 16     | 0     | "pizza dude"| america| 169    | 50
```

How do I find rows with at least 3 columns the same. These 3 columns, can be any of the 3 columns above.

In this df, I would return
rows 1 and 3(since age, gender, and height are the same)

```
Id  | age    | gender| occupation  | region | height | weight(kg)
100 | 16     | 0     | "plumber"   | na     | 169    | 20
600 | 16     | 0     | "pizza dude"| america| 169    | 50
```

I'm not quite sure how to code this up. Any ideas?

Comment: Can your result have something like:
900 | 16     | 1     | "plumber"| america| 169    | 50.

Comment: yea, since age, occupation, and height are the same as row 1, then this will be considered a duplicate of row 1 and by transitive property row 3